# Laravel: How to get Models out of query results?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Suppose I have a query that, among other things, returns user id's, this query was built using `DB::table()...` rather than using the models, so, as a result, I got a collection with arrays for each retrieved row, something like this:

```
user_id | calculated_data
--------+----------------
      1 |     123
      2 |     111
      3 |     222
    ... |     ...
```

Supose I store this collection on a `$data` variable, of course if I do a `foreach ($data as $d) { $d->user_id ... }` will work.

But I want this query to return something more like what the ORM does, so instead `user_id`s, return User models so I can do, for example, a `$data->user->name`

Can this be even done? if so, how?

Comment: 5.8.32 to be precise

Comment: @miken32 just to know but what was wrong in my tagging of this question?

Comment: Version-specific tags are best used for version-specific features. So if a new feature was introduced in v 5 and you were asking about it, you’d use laravel-5. This is a basic feature of the framework that’s been there since day 1 so the version-agnostic tag is sufficient.

Comment: *among other things* is the reason nobody can really help you out. We don't know how you get to the presented table and what these other things are there. You will either have to resort to `User::find(...);` Or ORM-ize the original DB statement with (right) join requests.

Comment: You should include example queries and data in your questions in stead of commenting on answers why they won't work for you. People want to help and need all the information to do so.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `hydrate()` function, it accepts an `array` of `stdClass` objects (or even associative arrays AFAIR) as input and returns a `collection` of `Eloquent Models`, so you can do things like this:

```php
$result = DB::table('users')->take(10)->get();
$users = App\User::hydrate($result->all());
```

You can even get a collection of `Eloquent Models` directly from a RAW query with the `fromQuery()` function, i.e.:

```php
$users = App\User::fromQuery('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id > ?', [2])
```

Update: If in your collection you don't have all the fields to `hydrate` a model, you can preload all the users you need with *one query* and modify your `collection`, i.e.:

```php
$users = App\User::find($data->pluck('user_id'));
$data->transform(function($item) use($users) {
            $item->user = $users->where('id', $item->user_id)->first()
            return $item;
        });
```

Comment: It seems that with `hydrate()` you must pass a whole object (I mean the data), sort to speak, to convert it to models, in my case I don't have a mirror representation of the object since it contains other data, but thanks, it was interesting to know about this!

Comment: @luisfer you posted a kind of generic question, without the query and without the data dump, and you get a generic answer, IMHO this is the best you can find with the details you gave.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Eloquent to call value the "ORM way" I did not find anything related to the query builder in relation to ORM.

You could do something like this:

```
$flights = App\Flight::all(); 

foreach ($flights as $flight) {
    echo $flight->name;
}
```

And in the ORM way you would get the user like this:

```
foreach ($flights as $flight) {
    echo $flight->user->name;
}
```

Of course you would need to setup the correct relations.

Comment: Yeah I know how to use the ORM. But in this case, I have to do more than my knowledge on the ORM can do, I have two views (not tables) to provide the data I need

Answer (score 0):

```
// initial query will return collection of objects
$query = DB::table('user_something')
   ->join('users', 'users.id', 'user_something.user_id');

// You could cast it to the model query, by using fromSub.
// Make sure to alias a subquery same as the model's name,
// otherwise it would not be able to parse models data
User::fromSub($query, 'users');

// The most robust way is to get table name from the model
User::fromSub($query, User::make()->getTable());
```