# Laravel Querybuilder method with Join is not calling accessor in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

My query is like this

```
$query = type::select(DB::raw(
                "CONCAT(users.first_name,' ',users.last_name) 
                as full_name"
            ));

    $query->join('users', function ($join) {
                        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'type.uid')
                            ->where('type.is_deleted', 0);
                    })

   return $query->where('type.id', 123)->get();
```

and accessormethod in user model

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
}
```

But it is not calling that method and not returning fullName as output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: How to get Models out of query results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57581708/laravel-how-to-get-models-out-of-query-results)

Comment: you are not using Eloquent to pull the results. So you are not actually getting the models. You can use the `Model::hydrate()` method for getting the models out of your query

Comment: @CornelRaiu I have never used hydrate(). can you help me how to use it? Do I need to remove DB::RAW?

Comment: Look it the link I added in the other comment

Comment: @CornelRaiu I have checked that but didn't get how to use with my scenario

Comment: @CornelRaiu Do I need to keep CONCAT? or concatation will be done from accessor?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Model::hydrate()` method.
Something like this.

I did not test it but it should give you a headstart

```
$query = App\User::select();
// or $query = DB::table(User::make()->getTable());
// or $query = User::select(['users.id', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name']);

$query->join('subjects', function ($join) {
    $join->on('users.id', '=', 'type.uid')->where('type.is_deleted', 0);
})

$users = App\User::hydrate($query->where('type.id', 123)->get()->toArray());
```

You need to make sure that you are getting the columns needed in your accessor.

Comment: Do I need to keep CONCAT? or concatation will be done from accessor?

Comment: TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::hydrate() must be of the type array, object give

Comment: even after trying this, User::hydrate($data->toArray()), it is not working as expected

Comment: @BhumiShah I updated the answer. Let me know if that is ok.